# C++ vector strange behaviour

Tags: c++

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<double> a;
    while (a.size() <= 10)
        a.push_back(2);
    cout << a[15] << endl;
}
```

I would expect it to crash when asked to access 15-th element of a, but it does not (outputs 0 on my system).  What gives?  Is this some new feature in gcc or something?

Comment: It might crash, it might not. That's the beauty of undefined behavior.

Comment: stop saying that.. vectors can grow their capacity! if you make a test you will see that his vector has 16 of capacity which means a[15] is valid!!

Comment: @riskio `a[15]` is only valid if `a.size() > 15`.  Otherwise, it's undefined behavior, according to the standard.  (And in fact, it will probably crash in a debug build.)

Comment: @JamesKanze with valid i meant that it doesn t cause a crash but the memory is holded by vector..

Comment: @riskio Except that it does cause a crash, if you've activated container debugging.  It could also cause a crash because the memory read doesn't contain a valid floating point value (since it hasn't been initialized, it could contain anything).

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing an invalid memory location which leads to undefined behavior. So anything might happen.

Answer (score 1):

[This references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5b%5d/) says that it

> Returns a reference to the element at position **n** in the vector
>   container.
>
> A similar member function, **vector::at**, has the same behavior as this
>   operator function, except that **vector::at** signals if the requested
>   position is out of range by throwing an exception.

So, this might or might not crash.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that, and it was unclear from that reference what happens if n is out of bounds.  If they had explicitly stated that n out of bounds results in undefined behaviour, I wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

the `operator[]` does no bounds checking, and in this case you were *un*lucky and the address at that location could be read without causing a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

it is not strange..a vector grows it's size when it is inserted a.size()-1 element..so now you have kind of 20 elements.. (maybe not 20 but more than 11 (= )

Comment: In this trivial example what is at the location may work, in real world who knows what's at that location. The storage may be there, but there is no object constructed at that site - therefore accessing it is undefined behaviour - endof.

Comment: it is not an advice..i did answer to his question..but c++ programmers should know stl containers and should know that memory management it's all their responsability so it s in every c++ programmers the responsibility to do the safer things..

Answer (score 0):

Because the growth of the vector could be larger than 15 when you access it?

Check the `capacity()`.

Comment: `capacity()` is irrelevant here (and is only guaranteed to be greater than 11).  It's `size()` that matters.

Comment: No, `capacity()` returns the size of the allocated storage capacity. `size()` returns the number of element in the container.

Comment: And how does that make it relevant here?  (Or contradict what I said.)  All `capacity()` guarantees is that there will be no reallocations (and no invalidation of iterators, etc.) until the size exceeds the value it returns.  It does **not** authorize accessing beyond the end of the initialized values, and in practice, good implementations will not allow it, at least in debug mode.

Answer (score -1):

I the memory you are reading is inside your program it won't crash, c++ does not bounds checking

Comment: Where does it say that in the standard.  The implementations of `std::vector` that I use do bounds checking, at least if the correct options are passed to the compiler.  (His code crashes with g++, when compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`---an option which should be generally used for all compilations, until the profiler says otherwise.)